# Customize req.body Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to know, is it possible to make custom req.body which is will be send to MongoDB. In my case, I have req.body like this : 
`{ f_name: 'John', l_name: 'Doe', phone: '4521234892345' }`
But, what i expected is :

```
{
 "f_name": {
  "type": "text",
  "value": "John"
 },
 "l_name": {
  "type": "text",
  "value": "Doe"
 },
 "phone": {
  "type": "number",
  "value": "212348923"
 }
}
```

The value of `type` are coming from HTML `<input />` in a form. 
 For example : 
`<input type="text" name="f_name" value="John">` 
and 
`<input type="number" name="phone" value="212348923">`

My backend :

```
app.post("/api/leads/:userId/:formId", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

My other backend:

```
app.get("/view/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const result = await Form.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    // console.log(result);
    // console.log(err)
    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    res.render("form", {
     data
    });
});
```

My Frontend(form.pug) :

```
    form(action='/api/leads/'+data._user+'/'+data._id, method='POST')
      mixin FieldGroup(id, type, label, text)
        div(classname="field-group")
          .field-group__inner
            if label
              label(classname="capitalize")= text
              |  :
              .field-row__inner
                input(id=id classname="input input--text" type=type name=text.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('_'))
            else
              .field-row__inner
                input(id=id classname="input input--text" name=text.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('_') type=type placeholder=text)
      each val, index in data.formElement.fieldRows
        .field-row 
          .field-row__inner
            each fieldGroup, i in val.fieldGroups
              +FieldGroup(fieldGroup.id, fieldGroup.type, fieldGroup.useLabel, fieldGroup.labelPlaceholder)
      .is-center.m-top-30
        button.button.is-success(type='submit') Submit
```

Comment: yes, possible, but you have to change according to your requirement in backend , serverside, from where its getting saved.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty can you give me clue or suggestion how to do that?

Comment: please edit the questation and add your backend structure and schema aswell.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML  in a form. Like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="f_name[type]" value="text">
<input type="text" name="f_name[value]" value="John">
```

and in your app.js body-parser extended should be true like

```
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, if you have control of the front end, just make your form mirror your data model. Otherwise, transform you data at your server before it makes a call to your database. It's what we all have to do.

Comment: well I am confused in this section, can you give references?

Comment: I feel like you might need to be more specific. Are you struggling doing the data transformation? If so, that's totally fine. Just make it nice and clear: this is the data structure I get, this is the data structure I want.